# Access C# Singleton from class without passing it into the class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, visual-studio-2012, singleton

This is what I'm talking about.

```
public sealed class ObjectZ {
    static readonly ObjectZ _instance = new ObjectZ();
    private ObjectZ() {}
    public static ObjectZ Instance{
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

I want to access this pointer...

```
ObjectZ obj = ObjectZ.Instance;
```

from another class without passing it into the constructor or a method and setting it. If I do this line from another class, do I get the same object?

I'm used to Objective-C, where you can retrieve a singleton style object from the UIApplicationDelegate in one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ObjectZ.Instance` value will return the same object no matter where in the code you access it from.  It is backed by a static field and static fields are essentially global.

There are a couple of cases though where static fields will have different values.

- If the static fields are in different `AppDomain` instances.  Typically though applications only have a single `AppDomain`
- If the static field is contained in a generic type then different instantiations will have different static field values

Comment: I'm working with a very large code base (.Net 2.0 application). Is there an easy way to tell if a project has multiple AppDomains?

Comment: AppDomains are a runtime phenomenon. An application could start off with one AppDomain, and add more later. The typical case where this would be seen is in ASP.NET, where multiple AppDomains may exist while the first is being quiesced and a new one is started.